# How to correct a twist in a 2x4?

Tags: wood

I making a work bench surface and after putting the boards together in a rectangle I noticed a twist in one of the 2x4s. The result is that it will not lay flat anymore.

Will adding joists help correct this issue? The boards will act as a support for a piece of plywood that will go on top.

Comment: This question is substanially similar to: [How can I straighten twisted studs?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91159/how-can-i-straighten-twisted-studs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Buy another 2x4 that is straight.  If it is for a workbench top you should be buying the best quality you can find which might cost $2 more.

Comment: Sometimes they will even just let you exchange one 2x4 (or other lumber) for another, assuming you haven't cut it down yet.

Comment: Read the title, and was going to post this same answer.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - most BB will let you if it is within a week.  Actually most BB will let you return anything depending who is working the counter.

Comment: @Tester101 - When wood wants to twist it is much stronger than you think.  Bind it to more wood and watch it try to twist that wood too.

Comment: @DMoore I find a pleasant demeanor and a smile are about all the reciept I need to make an exchange. As for correcting the twist in lumber, I find it's something only to be attempted with expensive and/or non-replaceable lumber.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - Exactly.  Just hearing "2x4" is enough to know it isn't worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

It's not uncommon for a softwood frame built independently of any support structure to have a twist. It's usually resolved when you add your top sheet and anchor the assembly to walls, legs, etc. Gravity helps over time as well. I wouldn't bother taking anything apart unless it's convenient.